# A few precalculus questions for review

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a. Take the square root, add 3, then multiply by 1/4

$$\begin{align}
\ &f(x) = \sqrt{x}+3({\frac{1}{4}})\\  
\end{align}$$
This is the answer I came to, however I am receiving an incorrect answer.

b. Let f(x) = x^2 + 9x.
Evaluate the function f at the indicated values. (If an answer is undefined, enter UNDEFINED

$$\begin{align}
\ &f(-x) = {\frac{1}{x^x}}-9x \\  
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\ & f(\frac{1}{a})= Undefined\\  
\end{align}$$
I don't understand why I am getting this wrong.

c. Find f(a), f(a + h) and the difference quotient f(a + h) − f(a) / h,where h ≠ 0

$$\begin{align}
\ & \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}= {\frac{7}{a+h+6}}-\frac{7}{(a+6)h} \\  
\end{align}$$

However, I also am getting this wrong.

Please explain
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain how you got the term $\frac1{x^x}$ in b?

Comment: Is the function in (c) $$f(x) = \frac{7}{x + 6}$$?

Comment: Take the square root $\Rightarrow \sqrt{x}$, add $3 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x}+3$, then multiply by $1/4 \Rightarrow (\sqrt{x}+3)\times (1/4)$, you are multiplying only $3$ with $1/4$

Answer (score 1):

For (a), the instructions say to add 3, then multiply the result (the whole thing) by $\frac{1}{4}$, so you should get
$$(\sqrt{x}+3)\cdot\frac{1}{4}.$$
You parenthesized the expression wrongly, giving the wrong answer.

For (b), to find $f(-x)$ or $f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$, just substitute that value for $x$ in the definition of $f$:
\begin{align*}
  f(-x) &= (-x)^2 + 9(-x) = x^2-9x \\
  f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) &= \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^2 + 9\cdot\frac{1}{a}
      = \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{9}{a} = \frac{9a+1}{a^2}.
\end{align*}

Finally, for (c), to compute $f(a+h)$, substitute $a+h$ for $x$ in the function definition:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} &= \frac{\frac{7}{(a+h)+6)}-\frac{7}{a+6}}{h} \\
      &= \frac{7(a+6)-7(a+h+6)}{h(a+h+6)(a+6)} \\
      &= -\frac{7h}{h(a+h+6)(a+6)} \\
      &= -\frac{7}{(a+h+6)(a+6)}.
\end{align*}
I think you were probably insufficiently careful in keeping track of what was divided by what in your fractions.

Comment: Beautiful, do you think it matters if I add the * sign between the:$$\begin{align}
(\sqrt{x}+3) & * {\frac{1}{4}} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: No. $*$, $\cdot$, and nothing all conventionally mean multiplication. Your mileage may vary depending on the expectations of your teacher.

Comment: Ok, I expected so. Thanks you for your assistance.

Comment: Excuse me but I made a mistake in (c) the function is: $$\begin{align}
f({x}) & = {\frac{7}{x+6}} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I thought you might have, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated!